# Mysql connection established over public IP

Tags: php, mysql, networking, remote-access, ubuntu-server

I have a web server an a mysql server. Both are Ubunutu server 16. My Mysql version is 5.7. And I also have Laravel 5.4 on my web server.
Both servers can ping each other on local network.
When I try to connect to database server through local network which is in 172.16.0.0 range, it tries to connect through public IP over internet. And as I have not created user for public IP it cannot connect.
What's the problem ?
How can I forward port 3306 to the local IP addresses ?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. What are the IP addresses and the subnet masks?  Also, how do you know _it tries to connect through public IP over internet_? In your web code how do you attempt to connect to the database?

Comment: @AbraCadaver When I try establish connection I get this error
Host '185.x.x.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL serve. Which is my public IP.
And also when I try:
telnet 172.16.101.14 3306
I get the same error as above.

Comment: I Agree with @AbraCadaver. This looks more like a "Routing-Problem" of two servers beeing connected localy as well. You should better start to identify the *real* (connection-)problem, and ask on http://superuser.com/ - or if it's really a Server-Issue, maybe https://serverfault.com/ as well.

Comment: That may be correct. But there are no problems on LAN. As the two servers can ping each other.

Comment: Please show how you are "trying" to connect - there is a reason, why the connections tries to use the public IP rather than the local one.

Comment: In terminal:
telnet 172.16.101.14 3306
result:
Trying 172.16.101.14...
Connected to 172.16.101.14.
Escape character is '^]'.
GHost '185.x.x.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL serverConnection closed by foreign host.

185.x.x.x is my public IP.